# How to extract values from cypher Variable Length Relationships query?

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am trying extract name column from cyper Variable Length Relationships query results. But not sure how to get the name column from complex object .
Below is the code which I was trying but couldn't get success.

or

Please advise if any way adjust the query to get specified value .

```
session.run('match path=(n)-[:DATA*..3]-(m) where n._nme=$source and 
m._nme=$destination return path ', 
{source:source,destination:destination}).then(function(result) {
result.records.forEach(function(record){
console.log(record._fields[0].properties.nme);
});
});
```

Here is record json

```
records: (215) […]
​[0…99]
​​[100…199]
​​[200…214]
​​length: 215
​​<prototype>: Array []
​summary: Object { statementType: "r", plan: false, profile: false, … }
​<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Here expanded json

```
records: (215) […]
​​  [0…99]
​​​     0: {…}
​​​​            _fieldLookup: Object { path: 0 }
            ​​​​_fields: (1) […]
                ​​​​​0: {…}
                    ​​​​​​end: Object { identity: "110", labels: (1) […], properties: {…} }
​​​​​​                  length: 3
                    ​​​​​​segments: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
                    ​​​​​​start: Object { identity: "92", labels: (1) […], properties: {…} }
                    ​​​​​​<prototype>: Object { … }
                ​​​​​length: 1
                ​​​​​<prototype>: Array []
        ​​​​keys: Array [ "path" ]
​​​​        length: 1
​​​​        <prototype>: Object { … 

}
```

Comment: Can you show in your question what a `record` looks like (say, in JSON)?

Comment: Do you really need the whole path back? If you just need the nodes of the path, or the values of nodes in the path, then you can adjust your Cypher. Also, you really should be using labels in your pattern, as you can't take advantage of any index lookups without them, provided you've created indexes for lookup by `_nme` property on certain labels.

Comment: Would like to get node values to show in the UI. How to adjust cypher query ?